# how to load an html fragment in rails with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am wondering how I may `jQuery.load` an HTML fragment returned by a model's `show` action. For example, `$("#container").load("/posts/34")`. The problem with this is that it returns the view I want embedded in the layout, as if I were to visit that url in the browser. I *only* want the `Post`'s `show` HTMl fragment.

Thanks!

**Clarification**: I want the `show` view to continue to render within the application layout when going to the `show` action in my browser. I'm merely trying to figure out how to fetch *only* the html of the `show` view for when I want to load it asynchronously with jQuery. I have seen guides in which they create `show.js.erb` and then render the html view there, but it seems pretty messy to me, escaping all of that html for javascript. If this is the accepted and proper way of doing this though I guess I'll follow the standard. I was just wondering if it were possible to only fetch the html of a particular view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use :layout => false in your render statement to return the fragment without the layout:

```
def show
  ...
  render(:layout => false) if request.xhr?
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pan I appreciate the response, however, I want the show action to work fine normally, that is, when I visit the show action in my browser, of course I want it to render within my application layout. I'm only trying to figure out how to fetch it without the layout for when I want to load it asynchronously with jquery. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend simply adding a parameter to the call so that you know it's coming from an ajax request. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Pan, that might be the way to go.

Comment: I actually updated it so that you don't need to pass a parameter. Just use request.xhr? to check if it's an ajax request as opposed to a normal request.

Comment: Thanks. I adapted this to a respond_to block and it works beautifully so far. I appreciate it. This seems like the most intuitive/concise way to handle this.

Comment: I actually didn't know you could to that (+1)

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a GET parameter in the URL and put a condition in your controller:

```
def show
  render(:layout => false) if params['partial'] == 'true'
end
```

And javascript:

```
$('#container').load('/posts/34?partial=true')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support regular and AJAX requests you'll want to use a `respond_to` block.

Like so

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # renders index.html.erb automatically
  format.js { render 'show', :content_type=>'text/html', :layout=>false }
end
```

Comment: This isn't correct, `format.js` implies that the content is javascript, which it is not. This will cause Rails to send the response with an incorrect MIME type.

Comment: You're right. I've updated by example to set the content type.